# "unused arguments" error for even simplest glm function

Tags: r

my code is

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
```

however, when I run, it shows:

```
Error in list(counts, outcome, treatment) : unused argument (treatment)
```

and it seems that every "glm" function doesn't work in my R

Comment: Why do you have an uncaptured call to `data.frame`? It does nothing in this context.

Comment: I do not get an error with your code (AIC of 56.761).

Comment: I think maybe there are some problems with my r...

Comment: Echo, I'm probably going to vote to close as *"can no longer be reproduced"* since your code here does not produce an error for me. If it persists for you and **in a fresh R session**, then either you aren't giving us representative/actual code or something else I can't think of now.